# How can I stop my email address displaying in the Software Center comments?

Tags: software-center, privacy

Whenever I leave a comment in USC, my email address is displayed. This is not the case for other commenters. How can I prevent this?

Example: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/folder-color/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reviews use your Ubuntu SSO id. If you go to http://login.ubuntu.com, login, you should be able to change your full name. You may even be able to edit the review after you change your name.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it in Launchpad but that didn't do the trick. I'll go edit my reviews now.